# Prestashop detect page php_self

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I have a custom prestashop module that has to be restricted on doing actions inside the order confirmation page.
So, inside the module I placed one IF statement to detect the current page and if page is equal with order-confirmation, then skip it
The code is the following:

```
if ($this->context->controller->php_self != 'order-confirmation') {
    $this->context->controller->addJqueryPlugin(array('fancybox'));
}
```

But it doesn't work at all
Could someone tell me what's wrong about this code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In `FrontController.php` is a method `setMedia()`.

Line 980

```
if (Configuration::get('PS_QUICK_VIEW')) {
    $this->addjqueryPlugin('fancybox');
}
```

So if you have quick view enabled in store, the fancybox plugin gets loaded on every front page regardless of your hook logic.

Comment: No, I don't have quick view enabled, and still I am able to restrict the load of the plugin for some custom modules but not for order confirmation page..

Comment: Well I just tested your code and with quick view disabled, the plugin doesn't get loaded on order confirmation. You must have some other module that loads the plugin.

Comment: I don't really get it.. It's working in all other pages.. not in order confirmation.. what's that special about it?

Comment: Nothing special about it... at least on basic installation. I have no idea what modules or overrides you have installed on your shop, that would keep this plugin loading on order confirmations. And just to be clear we are talking about order confirmation page after the order has been created or are you talking about a page where you have to click 'I confirm my order'? Because that's a different page.

Comment: Well, after smashing my head on Prestashop logic, the line that was not functioning well was the if itself.. I have a if like this:if ($this->context->controller->php_self != 'countrypages' || $this->context->controller->php_self != 'order-confirmation') {, but as I can see, PS doesn't like the OR clause but works perfect with AND clause..

Comment: But, still don't get it, it should work with OR. If the page is countrypages OR order-confirmation don't load fancybox..

Comment: No, you have the OR and AND logic wrong. OR returns TRUE if **any** condition is TRUE it will execute IF block. AND means when **all** conditions are TRUE the block executes. Your if block says 'if page **IS NOT** countrypages or page **IS NOT** order-confirmation' then load plugin. You enter order-confirmation page and because page **IS NOT** countrypages, it loads the plugin.